# how to compile cpp file using cmd with Qt creator compiler

Tags: qt, gcc, cmd, compilation, mingw-w64

I am using Qt creator and its compiler minGW, I want to compile .cpp (//which is created not using Qt)file using this Qt creator compiler in CMD

need compiling information in cmd using Qt creator

c:>c:>c:\Qt\Qt6.2.6\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin gcc -o c:\Users\chandresh.bs\Desktop\CplusApp\Hello.cpp Hello
Access is denied.

c:>c:>c:\Qt\Qt6.2.6\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin g++ -o c:\Users\chandresh.bs\Desktop\CplusApp\Hello.cpp Hello
Access is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About compiler

Firstly, you have to understand **mingw-g++** compiler flags. The most simplest example of compiling using g++ is

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

In this example, `hello.cpp` is your file, flag `-o` tells to compiler that after this flag you provide name of executable. You are using Qt, so this example will **not** be able to compile your project. You need to **link** your project against Qt libraries. There's a lot of libraries and it will be quite difficult to do using only compiler.

### How to do it correctly?

Any project with big amount of libraries and files uses some **build** system.You write configuration file for your build system, after that you generate `Makefile` or something like this, and using `make` you can compile it. It's pretty simple to use, because you don't need to remember flags, write long commands to compile something. Also, **build** system helps you to make your code cross-platform, because it can be used on any OS. For this purposes, Qt uses **qmake**, that do all necessary things and let you compile project with one click in Qt Creator. You can simply use **qmake** generated in Qt Creator:

- Create folder `build` in your project folder
- open **cmd** and change command-line directory using `cd your-project-folder`
- Call **qmake** referencing the **.pro** file using `qmake project_name.pro`
- Call **make** to compile your project using configuration files by `make`

It's simpler than linking anything for every file you have. Hope it will help you!